# How to add mouseover eventlistener to xAxis area of Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts

I added mouseover eventlistener to `.highcharts-xaxis-labels` class of Highcharts. However it `console.log` only when mouseover on `<text>` not the rest of `.highcharts-xaxis-labels` class.

How can I add the eventlistener so that it `console.log` on mouseover all over the `.highcharts-xaxis-labels` class, not only on `<text>` inside the class? That would be the `<g>` with className `.highcharts-xaxis-labels`.

live example: https://jsfiddle.net/simazargar/sv9e1g5x/9/

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
  }]
}, chart => {
  document.querySelector('.highcharts-xaxis-labels')
  .addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
    console.log('mouseover');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Thanks for contributing. Could you please take a moment to [convert your jsfiddle link to "Stack Snippet"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/11107541) if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `pointer-events: bounding-box` style of the `.highcharts-xaxis-labels` CSS class:

```
.highcharts-xaxis-labels {
  pointer-events: bounding-box;
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bmykcLew/

Useful thread: [jQuery click isn't triggered on SVG <g> but on child elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57053276/jquery-click-isnt-triggered-on-svg-g-but-on-child-elements)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would not be possible unless we have a new `<rect>` with a new className such as `.highcharts-xaxis-box` which will also allow to style this area rather than only the labels (similar to what Highcharts has for Legend).

I will ask for a new feature https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/18082